# How to remove rows from a datascience table in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I  have a table with 4 columns filled with integer.  Some of the rows have a value "null" as its more than 1000 records with this "null" value, how can I delete these rows all at once? I tried the delete method but it requires the index of the row its theres over 1000 rows. Is there as faster way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using pandas? Add your code.

Comment: If you are using `pandas` then read this [10 minute guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/10min.html) to get the basics down. You should be able to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

use the 'drop.isnull()' function.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a row in a datascience package:

name_of_your_table.remove() # number of the row in the bracket

Answer (score 0):

Use the function:

```
name_of_your_table.dropna()
```

It will drop all the "null" values.

Answer (score 0):

#df is the original dataframe#
#The '-' operator removes the null values and re-assigns the remaining ones to df#

df=idf[-(df['Column'].isnull())]

Answer (score 0):

use dataframe_name.isnull() #To check the is there any missing values in your table.

use dataframe_name.isnull.sum() #To get the total number of missing values.

use dataframe_name.dropna() # To drop or delete the missing values.